# How to return rows with minimum and maximum column value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in a data warehouse that looks like this:

```
TicketNbr  Cpn  Start   End
279211      1   CHS     JFK  
295946      1   JFK     TPA  
279211      2   JFK     TPA  
234916      1   JFK     CHS
284916      1   JFK     CHS
279211      3   TPA     JFK
279211      4   JFK     CHS
```

I want to return rows with TicketNbr = 279211 and I only want to return the rows that have the minimum and maximum Cpn value. So from this table I want to return

```
TicketNbr  Cpn  Start   End       
279211      1   CHS     JFK
279211      4   JFK     CHS
```

I am not very proficient in SQL so I tried

```
SELECT
TicketNbr,
MIN(Cpn),
Start AS [StartCity],
End AS [EndCity]
FROM TKTExchange AS T
GROUP BY TicketNbr
WHERE TicketNbr = '279211'
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT  
    MAX(Cpn),
    Start AS [StartCity],
        End AS [EndCity]
    FROM TKTExchange
    GROUP BY TicketNbr) AS GT
ON T.TicketNbr = GT.TicketNbr
```

But GROUPBY doesn't work in this context. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `group by TicketNbr` you can get the min and max values you need and then join to the table. If there are more rows with equal `Cpn` they will all be returned:

```
select t.* from TKTExchange t
inner join (
  select TicketNbr, min(Cpn) mincpn, max(Cpn) maxcpn
  from TKTExchange
  group by TicketNbr
) g on g.TicketNbr = t.TicketNbr and t.Cpn in (g.mincpn, g.maxcpn)
```

You can add conditions like:

```
where t.TicketNbr = 279211
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `WITH TIES` in concert with `row_number()`

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 With Ties * 
 From  YourTable
 Where TicketNbr = 279211 
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By [TicketNbr] Order by Cpn Desc)
         *Row_Number() over (Partition By [TicketNbr] Order by Cpn Asc)
```

**Returns**

```
TicketNbr   Cpn Start   End
279211      1   CHS     JFK
279211      4   JFK     CHS
```

**[dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=10353064f45c2b1c3956f258d2a0ef98)**

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different method to the others using a CTE and windowed functions:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT *,
           MIN(Cpn) OVER (PARTITION BY TicketNbr) AS MinCpn,
           MAX(Cpn) OVER (PARTITION BY TicketNbr) AS MaxCpn
    FROM (VALUES(279211,1,'CHS','JFK'),  
                (295946,1,'JFK','TPA'),  
                (279211,2,'JFK','TPA'),  
                (234916,1,'JFK','CHS'),
                (284916,1,'JFK','CHS'),
                (279211,3,'TPA','JFK'),
                (279211,4,'JFK','CHS')) V(TicketNbr,Cpn,[Start],[End])
    WHERE V.TicketNbr = 279211)
SELECT V.Cpn,
       V.Cpn,
       V.[Start],
       V.[End]
FROM VTE V
WHERE V.Cpn = V.MinCpn
   OR V.Cpn = V.MaxCpn;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to select the top and bottom records, and then `UNION` them together into one dataset.  Such as:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1
     [TicketNbr]
    ,[Cpn]
    ,[Start]
    ,[End]
FROM [TKTExchange]
WHERE
    [TicketNbr] = '279211'
ORDER BY
    [Cpn] ASC) AS [A]

UNION

SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1
     [TicketNbr]
    ,[Cpn]
    ,[Start]
    ,[End]
FROM [TKTExchange]
WHERE
    [TicketNbr] = '279211'
ORDER BY
    [Cpn] DESC) AS [B]
```